# Android PopUp Not showing Due to InstallException

Tags: android, popup

My problem is thw following one: I have this Java code...

```
        Button boton = (Button) this.findViewById(R.id.button1);
    boton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            AlertDialog.Builder builderDlg = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this);
              builderDlg.setTitle("Exit");
              builderDlg.setMessage("¿Usted quiere retirarse?");
              builderDlg.setCancelable(false);
              builderDlg.setPositiveButton("Si",new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    MainActivity.this.finish();

                }
            });

              builderDlg.setNegativeButton("No",new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    dialog.cancel();

                }
            });
        }
    });
```

And when I start the Android Emulator, the popUp doesn't show itself and the following lines appear in the log...

```
[2013-02-17 19:35:33 - DialogPopUp] Failed to install DialogPopUp.apk on device 'emulator-5554': device not found
[2013-02-17 19:35:33 - DialogPopUp] com.android.ddmlib.InstallException: device not found
[2013-02-17 19:35:33 - DialogPopUp] Launch canceled!
```

It's a pitty because I wanted to check this silly thing but I am kinda stucked...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your emulator is either not running, or your connection to ADB has broken or become outdated. To fix this:

1. Close Eclipse and any running emulators
2. Restart your computer
3. Start Eclipse and launch your emulator
4. Try running your app now.

If it still doesn't work, check your run and debug configurations to make sure they point to the correct emulator.

Comment: Thankx for your answer... As soon as I arrived to home, I will check this... Cheers...

Comment: Hi !. Just wanted to post that I forgot to call this two methods: 1) create() 2) show(). Hope that will help... But a weird thing happened to me... Although I have created several avd's, eclipse keeps telling there are no available avd's... And I have no avd to choose... Do you know what could be the problem ?